# Comparing "0.1" to .1

Tags: java, string, double

I am working on understanding the limitations of double.  0.1 cannot be expressed in a finite system because it is a repeating binary value.  But, when I declare a variable and give it 0.1, it still prints as 0.1 and **not** .0999999999999999, 1.000000000000001 or something of the like.  But, if I add a variable that has 0.1 ten times, it comes out to .9999999999999999, which is what I would expect.

The real question is why is it printing exactly at 0.1 when I know that is impossible and I have proof that is not the true value?

```
double d  = 0.1;
System.out.printf("%.16f\n",d);
System.out.printf("%.16f", d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d);
```

What I am trying to do is compare a string literal to a double conversion to see if the value in the string can be exactly represented in double. For example:

".5" == .5?   Expected answer: Yes.

".1" == .1?   Expected answer: No.

The comparison I am trying is

```
number = new BigDecimal("0.1");
d = number.doubleValue();
if (number.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d))) == 0){
    // Doing something
}
```

Any help understanding why this is not distinguishing between values that can and cannot be represented by double would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `BigInteger` is correct here? Also, why don't you directly support `d` to the `BigDecimal` constructor?

Comment: You are correct, it should have been BigDecimal.  I was only trying to get the relevant bits of code and made that mistake.  I corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if a `String` represents a `double` value you can do this:

```
private static boolean isADouble(String s) {
    return new BigDecimal(s).equals(new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(s)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isADouble("0.1"));  // false
    System.out.println(isADouble("0.5"));  // true
}
```

This works because `new BigDecimal(s)` produces a `BigDecimal` exactly equal to the value represented by the `String`, whereas `new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(s))` is the exact value of the *closest* `double` to that value.

I will explain at the end why `number.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d))) == 0` does *not* work.

When you do

```
double d = 0.1;
System.out.println(d);
```

you get the answer `0.1` because `d` is the closest `double` to the "real" `0.1`. (`double d = 0.1;` *means* "make `d` the nearest `double` to `0.1`". When you write

```
System.out.println(d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d + d);
```

you see `0.9999999999999999` rather than `1`. The reason you don't see `1` is because there are `double` values closer to one than the answer (in fact one is a `double` value itself). There is no reason why the answer should be the closest `double` to one, because `d` wasn't really `0.1` in the first place (it was just close to it), and in any case when you add floating point numbers inaccuracies are introduced.

Finally, `number.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d))) == 0` does not work because even though `number.doubleValue()` is *not* exactly `0.1`, `Double.toString()` still converts it to the `String` `"0.1"` because there are no `double` values closer the "real" `0.1`.

Comment: *"Finally, number.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d))) == 0 does not work because"* you can't compare `BigInteger` with `BigDecimal` :). But you might be right, if OP would read the compiler errors and would use `number = new BigDecimal("0.1");` instead.

Comment: @Tom Good catch. I didn't notice `BigInteger` was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I did accidentally use BigInteger in the initial question.   I have edited it.  Thank you for the help.  I've never used the Bigs before and I'm trying to get them down.  I'm a little surprised that they don't have the Math class functions built into them.

Comment: @TomK They have some basic stuff like `#abs`, `#devide`, `#multiply`, `#plus`,  `#pow` and `#subtract`.

Comment: @TomK Many of the methods from `Math` wouldn't really make any sense in `BigDecimal`. `BigDecimal` is meant for accurate calculations e.g. financial calculations. It's not really meant for advanced maths. You can't even represent simple fractions like one third with a `BigDecimal`, let alone cube roots or trigonometric ratios. You'd need a specialist library for that kind of thing.

Comment: @pbabcdefp You cannot exactly represent one third in double, but Java provides good approximations to fractional powers and trigonometric ratios. For double, there is known precision and range, so it is possible to find easily computed functions that are good enough approximations to e.g. trig functions over the double range. BigDecimal has unlimited range and precision.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, I do see why some functions just wouldn't work without some kind limitation used.  After all if we tried to assign 1/3 to a BigDecimal without limiting the number of digits, I would like the computer to do something else besides adding 3 to the end of a never ended number.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Isn't your explanation contrary to your code? `isADouble("0.1")` should be `true` and not `false`.